# Almost everywhere convergence of continuous functions

Tags: measure-theory

If $f_n$,$f$ are continuous functions such that $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere then is it true that $f_n \to f$ pointwise?

Comment: $x \mapsto x^n$ tends almost everywhere to $x \mapsto 0$ on $[0,1]$ (but not pointwise).

Comment: Thank you! @Gerd